# Custom UIButton embedded image size

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

This is a followup question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017273/iphone-ipad-rounded-custom-button-and-png-files) and got a excellent reply. I still need to get clarified on some of the things.

Since my UIButton is a custom round one, I'm trying to accommodate the best embedded png file both for iPhone and iPad (non retina and retina). What I found is having a dimension of 40x40 (iPhone) and 72x72 (iPhone retina) works best for me. My question is I wanted to make sure what I'm doing is right here. So, what I did is scale down 512x512px to the specified sizes. Also, for iPad can I have 104x104 and 136x136 sizes?. Is this going to be a problem when displayed on the real devices (retina and non-retina) or during approval?.

Please help.

Comment: Why you don't use @2x postfix? yourFileName.png and yourFileName@2x.png? That don't work with you?

Comment: I'm doing that but the dimensions are different. What I have done is for iPhone non retina the height and width are 40x40 and for retina displays it is 72x72. Is this valid?. For iPad, I'm thinking of 104x104 and 136x136. Is this valid?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use postfix in your png file. For example `CustomButon.png` for iphone and `CustomButton@2x.png` for retina iphone, also `CustomButon~ipad.png` for ipad `CustomButton~ipad@2x.png` for retina ipad.

Code for that is simple `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomButton.png"];`

Hope that helps.

BTW. I belive that retina png should be twice higher/longer than normal.